# What is the subject in the following bold and italic clause?

Tags: sentence-construction

In this following context, what is the subject in the bold and italic clause?

How should I take this clause?

And does the phrase 'second to none' modify 'a master-mind'?

The passage:

> In Gautama the Buddha we have a master-mind from the East second to
> none ***so far as the influence on the thought and life of the human
> race is concerned***, and, sacred to all as the founder of a religious
> tradition whose hold is hardly less wide and deep than any other.

Source: P. 9
Buddhism in a Nutshell BY NARADA THERA

Comment: The author claims that the Buddha has had more *influence on the thought and life of the human race* than anyone else (or, perhaps, than any other master-mind from the East).

Answer (score 0):

> In Gautama the Buddha we have a master-mind from the East second to none ***so far as the influence on the thought and life of the human race is concerned***, and, sacred to all as the founder of a religious tradition whose hold is hardly less wide and deep than any other.

*so far as the influence on the thought and life of the human race is concerned* means **concerning the influence on the thought and life of the human race**.  This is a preposition phrase, not a clause.  There is no subject.

The object of preposition is **the influence on the thought and life of the human race**.

The meaning of that preposition phrase is what @Kate Bunting has explained.

In *a master-mind from the East second to none*, yes, *second to none* modifies *a master-mind*.